# MS Access 2003 Include Sub-Select queries in Reports in fields directly

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Im writing a report form for MS Access 2003 where I have to do some cross-referencing. Basically I have a text field within a report that should have this value:

```
SELECT Name from Standorte WHERE Eintrag = #Field
```

Please note that #Field is the name of an already selected (in the properties of the report) database field from a different database.

My question now is: How do I, most efficiently, get this subquery directly into my text field and working. I have tried with = and in () before, no dice.

Comment: Add this as the recordsource:   "=DLOOKUP(.....)"  it will let you lookup in a table useing critiera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this as the recordsource:   "=DLOOKUP(.....)"  it will let you lookup in a table using critiera.

See here: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php